# Why must a Hamiltonian be gapped to have "local" excitations?

Tags: condensed-matter, hamiltonian, topological-order, anyons

On page 4 of Kitaev's ["Anyons in an Exactly Solved Model and Beyond"](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0506438) he states

> The notion of anyons assumes that the underlying state has an energy gap (at least for topologically nontrivial quasiparticles). Otherwise excitations are not localizable and braiding may not be defined.

Why is a gap needed to localise the excitations and describe them as particles with a well defined location?

Comment: massless particles go brrrrrrr

Comment: (but really, you can measure the position of a particle meaningfully only up to their Compton wavelength)

Comment: Ok so am I to understand that a gapless system has no "mass gap" so the lowest excitation does not have a finite mass and therefore the Compton wavelength diverges, meaning that one can't meaningfully locate the excitation? How is the Compton wavelength defined on a lattice system where "distance" is in terms of discrete lattice vectors? Presumably in such a way that it still diverges for gapless systems but what about the gapped case? (cont...)

Comment: (cont...) Take the Kitaev Toric code system (eq. 3 in the paper I linked) which has two elementary excitations: charges on vertices and vortices on plaquettes. One can only meaningfully locate them up to the lattice vectors so presumably this is, in some sense, their Compton wavelength. Is there some expression for Compton wavelength on lattices which yields this result?

Forgive me if these are dumb / ill-defined questions, I don't have a QFT background.